# Multiple Resources in one project

Tags: c#

I want to create one project with different versions like

- Normal
- Purchased

So as per my version I want to change some detail of my project like if someone is using `Normal` then icon should be "Normal.png" and if my it's `Purchased` then all the form should have icon of "Purchased.png".

Currently what happens is I wrote a code on condition base in every form.
Is there any way from where I can avoid this?

Is there any way from which I can create a new resource file and during compiling time tool will decide which resource file to use?

Comment: What are you using? Windows Forms? WPF? ASP.NET?

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358495/same-source-multiple-targets-with-different-resources-visual-studio-net-2008) may help - it dealt with switching sets of resources based on the build configuration.

Comment: @Conrad Clark - I am using Windows forms.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a static "theme" class that you can call when loading a windows form--and then pass it the current form.  Depending on the current theme (in this case, "Normal" or "Purchased"), manipulate the form accordingly.

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899364/apply-changes-to-mainforms-form-icon-at-runtime) for an example of changing a form's icon dynamically with code using resources.

You can also bind properties of controls to application settings -- see [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yyxh69h.aspx) for more on that.  (This wouldn't apply for the form icon, but it could help with other changes you want to make based on Normal/Purchased behavior).

Comment: Agreed, but what I want to change everything with this, even if I am compiling with Normal application icon should be same as form icon.

Comment: To change the application icon during install, I would probably use two separate Windows installer projects, one for Normal and one for Purchased, and specify the separate application icons there.  In VS2010, you can specify which projects are compiled under which configuration.  I think that might be less error-prone than trying to use custom actions or something to dynamically change the installer settings.