# MSBuild conditional to dynamically add resource files

Tags: file, msbuild, resources, conditional-statements

I've been attempting to modify my project's .csproj file, that will include one of two different resource(resx) files that will depend on what the build configuration is at the current time.

I've tried to use conditionals to differentiate the inclusion, something like:

Then proceeded to add the files that were located in different directories. However, when building I've either gotten errors or the build just ignored the conditionals and added the default resx files.

I was hoping someone might know how to conditionally add resx files depending on the current build configuration?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure this could work since the different files will likely cause different autogenerated code to be included as well? so you'd have classes with different names and end up with unresolved references or similar. doesn't mean it's impossible, but it would be good to have a sample to test

Comment: A co-worker brought me to this page, so it seems like it is viable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2358495/same-source-multiple-targets-with-different-resources-visual-studio-net-2008
The Debug and Release configurations, but my own Production configuration seems to lose reference to one of the other projects. The one that I'm changing to compile with different resources.